# Plot of piecewise function is not bounded properly

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I am trying to plot a piecewise function that gets bounded above and below a certain value (e.g).

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{-10, -Exp[-x] + 1 <= -10}, {-Exp[-x] + 1, 
x < 0}, {Exp[x] - 1, x < 3}, {10, 
10 <= Exp[x] - 1}}], {x, -10, 10}]
```

The functional forms of the two pieces are -Exp[-x]+1 (for any values of that piece below 10 the function is set equal to -10)  and Exp[x]-1 (for any values of that piece above 10 the value is set equal to 10. The graph should roughly look like this

[image: Plot graph]

Although the first two pieces work just fine, the third piece does not get bounded automatically and I have to use a numerical solution (x<2.3978), which might cause me issues. This is the graph I get.

[image: Wrong plot]

Does anyone know of a way to make this work? Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Piecewise gets evaluated begining from the left until the condition is True, you can simply change the position of the parts like that:

```
    Plot[Piecewise[
        {{-10, -Exp[-x] + 1 <= -10}, 
         {-Exp[-x] + 1, x < 0}, 
         {10, 10 <= Exp[x] - 1}, 
         {Exp[x] - 1, True}}], 
         {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves my problem in my preferred way. Can you please explain how the True condition works, and why my formulation was causing problems?

Comment: Your formulation didn't work, because like m_goldberg showed,  the two parts of the curve fit together at x=2.3979. Your condition was  x>3. Bringning the conditon  10<=Exp[x]-1 at the third position, it is fullfilled from x>2.3979, since testing of Piecwise begins from the left. The True at the forth part means, this parts is taken if none of the other conditions is True.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute where the middle section really reaches 10. The correct numerical solution is at `x = 2.3979`.

```
With[{a = NSolve[Exp[x] - 1 == 10, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]},
  f[x_] := 
    Piecewise[
      {{-10, -Exp[-x] + 1 <= -10},
      {-Exp[-x] + 1, x < 0},
      {Exp[x] - 1, x < a},
      {10, x >= a}}]]

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I came up with a very similar solution, but I would like to avoide Solve and relying on a numerical solution because I will introduce parameters later on, which might cause errors.